# how to execute the xml query using xmldataReader in c# from oracle

Tags: c#, oracle

I have xml query as below

```
cmd1 = new OracleCommand
                  (@"   select  XMLElement(
         ""Person"",XMLAttributes(
                                        'test' as ""TEST""
                                       ),
                    XMLElement(""Body"" ,
                    XMLElement(""SenderID"",'xxx')
                                       ),

                       (select XMLAgg(XMLElement(""Person"" , 
                                       XMLElement(""FirstName"",FirstName),
                                       XMLElement(""ContactNumber"",ContactNumber),
                                       XMLElement(""BirthDate"",BirthDate),
                                       XMLElement(""Gender"",Gender),
                                       XMLElement(""Nationality"",Nationality),
                                       XMLElement(""City"",City)

                                        )  )
                          from member

                          )
                      )

                    AS ""RESULT"" 
               From dual ",conn);
```

XmlReader xml_reader = cmd1.ExecuteXmlReader();

This last line throws an error:

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

If I use

```
OracleDataReader rdr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
```

I get this error:

> ORA-00936: missing expression

but the query is running in toad without any error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code above is not valid C#.  You would need to double all of double-quote characters in your verbatim string.  That aside, the next thing I would do would be to assign the string containing your query to a variable and write out its contents using `Console.WriteLine,` or a logging framework if you're using one.  That way you can take a look at the query that your code will be sending to the database.  It probably isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @LukeWoodward ya u r correct..I need to double all double quotes ..it is there in code when i posted it here it missed..edited the question..Also i debug the pgm and got the query from cmd and run it on toad successfully

Comment: I can't reproduce the error you get running your code with an `OracleDataReader`.  If you want to use an `XmlReader` you need to add a line `cmd1.XmlCommandType = OracleXmlCommandType.Query;` before you call `cmd1.ExecuteXmlReader()`.

Comment: @LukeWoodward i tried your solution..it is working now but it give uwanted tags as root <ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <RESULT>

Comment: You'll just have to deal with those extra elements.  Sure, your query will only ever return one row, but ODP.NET has to handle queries that return multiple rows.  The result of such a query has to be returned as a single XML document, so some level of wrapping is inevitable.